# C program to find growing numbers in an inverval

Tags: c, loops, numbers

First, sorry for my english and if I'm not explaining good enough. I hope the output of my code will help you get the idea what is it about. The problem with it is that , the way I've made it, it will work only for up to 999(3 digit number). I guess there should be a loop that  "doesn't care" how much digits there are and just does what it has to be done.

```
int main(){
int n, m, k, digit1, digit2, digit3, p, a = 0;
do{
    printf("Enter m and n (m < n):\n"); scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    if (m < n) {
        break;
    }
    else printf("\Error - m > n! Try again.\n\n");
} while (a == 0);

printf("Output:\n");
for (k = m; k <= n; k++){
    p = k;
    do{
        digit3 = p % 10; //123 % 10 = 3         13%10 = 3 == p/10 +1
        digit1 = p / 100; //123 / 100 = 1
        digit2 = (p / 10) % 10; // (123 /10) = 12%10 = 2 
        if (p > 100){
            if ( digit2 == digit1 + 1 && digit3 == digit2 + 1){
                printf("%d ", k);
            } break;
        }
        if (digit3 == ((p / 10) + 1)) {
            printf("%d ", k);
        } break;
        p = p / 10;
    } while (p > 0);
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
    Enter m and n (m < n):
    1 999
    Output:
    1 12 23 34 45 56 67 78 89 123 234 345 456 567 678 789
```

This output is correct and it is what the program has to do. Unfortunately I can't come up with loop to make it work with more than 999. It should output all numbers (in the interval entered by the user) in which each digit is bigger (by 1) than the previous.

Comment: Your approach doesn't scale, because you are using individual variables instead of arrays. Arrays are explained here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Arrays_and_strings

Comment: "I hope the output of my code will help you get the idea what is it about." No it doesn't. I don't want to guess your problem. What is a valid number? Why 1 is ok and 2 or 3 is not? State the problem clearly by editing your question.

Comment: A valid number is one that has ascending digits, like in 12 23; 123 etc.

Comment: @JustSteve I'll try again: Why 1 is ok and 2 or 3 is not? Shouldn't all single digit numbers be valid?

Comment: To be honest maybe 1 should't be there, but anyway. I think no single digit should be valid.

Comment: @JustSteve Well, who gave you the problem statement should clarify the point. It's hard to solve a problem whose statement is undefined! What is the point in the problem statement which makes you think that "no single digit should be valid"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take. Divide the problem into parts: you need a function to check if a number is "growing", meaning that every digit in its base 10 representation is the following of the one corresponding to the following power of 10, up to the highest non zero one. (Harder than it looks to express this concept formally).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool growing(unsigned int x) 
{
    //if (x < 10)
    //    return false;
    unsigned int last = x % 10 + 1;
    while (x>0) {
        unsigned int cur = x % 10;
        x /= 10;
        if (cur != last-1)
            return false;
        last = cur;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int m = 1;
    unsigned int n = 123456789;

    for (unsigned int i = m; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (growing(i)) {
            printf("%i ", i);
        }
    }
}
```

You should make up your mind on whether a single digit should be accepted or not. If yes, uncomment the first two lines.

Obviously the highest possible growing number is 123456789.

EDIT: A functionless version which directly moves the function into the for loop:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int m = 1;
    unsigned int n = 123456789;

    for (unsigned int i = m; i <= n; ++i) {
        unsigned int x = i;
        bool growing = true;
        //if (x < 10)
        //    growing = false;
        unsigned int last = x % 10 + 1;
        while (x>0) {
            unsigned int cur = x % 10;
            x /= 10;
            if (cur != last - 1)
                growing = false;
            last = cur;
        }

        if (growing) {
            printf("%i ", i);
        }
    }
}
```

You can get a slightly faster version with a break after setting growing to false.

*Useless rant*: I don't understand why people keep teaching I/O before the students can understand basic stuff. Not teaching functions, but writing one (`main`) without realizing it, and calling others (`scanf`, `printf`) without knowing anything about pointers. I'm curious on how the teacher justifies the `&`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. We still haven't studied functions, guess I'll have to check that myself.

Comment: @JustSteve Edited my answer with a "functionless" version. Remember to mark an answer as accepted for other people to know.

Comment: Done. Thanks  a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to keep track of all the number of digits at once.
All you need to check is that the last digit is one more than the second last

Something like this perhaps

```
int main(){
int n, m, k, digit1, digit2, digit3, p, a = 0;
do{
    printf("Enter m and n (m < n):\n"); scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    if (m < n) {
        break;
    }
    else printf("\Error - m > n! Try again.\n\n");
} while (a == 0);

printf("Output:\n");
k = m;
while(k++ <= n){
    int p = k;
    int flag = 0;
    int num;

    while(p > 10){
        // Get the last digit
        // in case of 123 -> 3
        num = p % 10;
        // Reduce p by 10
        // 123 -> 12
        p = p/10;
        // check 3 == 12%10 + 1
        // if this is correct go back to start of the loop
        // we may have more digits
        if(num  == p % 10 + 1) continue;
        // So the digits dont match, set the flag
        // break out of the loop
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }    
    // Outside the loop check the flag and print
    if(k > 10 && !flag)
        printf("%d ",k);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems to not work. I tried to change few stuff and still can't get it to work. :/

Comment: It doesn't output anything

Comment: Well yea that is just the logical part, hold on. I edited. now?

Comment: Somehow it works now. I understood it was only the logical part and I've put it as replacement of my loop, the only difference i did was putting flag and num at the top int. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution to the problem. It works with strings rather than numbers, and thus is less efficient but maybe easier to understand:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int m, n, i, j;
    char buf[20], c, last;
    _Bool ascending;

    puts("Enter m and n (m < n):");
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    if (m >= n) {
        fprintf(stderr, "m must be smaller than n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    puts("Output:");
    for (i = m; i < n; i++) {
        sprintf(buf, "%d", i);
        ascending = true;
        last = 0;
        for (j = 0; buf[j] != 0; j++) {
            c = buf[j];
            if (last != 0 && last != c - 1) {
                ascending = false;
                break;
            } else {
                last = c;
            }
        }
        if (ascending) {
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, it's output looks slightly different:

```
Enter m and n (m < n):
1 999
Output:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 12 23 34 45 56 67 78 89 123 234 345 456 567 678 789
```

I wonder what the actual rules are, because the numbers between 2 and 9 are note more or less ascending than 1, aren't they?

And here's the output for a bigger number:

```
Enter m and n (m < n):
1 10000
Output:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 12 23 34 45 56 67 78 89 123 234 345 456 567 678 789 1234 2345 3456 4567 5678 6789
```

Comment: Yeah the problem is I'm also not 100% what the output is. I couldn't find a better way to explain/translate the rules. I couldn't even understand what it was supposed to do(in my language) and when I asked the teacher she said " it should output numbers like 1234 for example". At first , for some reason I was thinking it should output like this - for example in 20 to 40, to output 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 34 35 36 37 38 39.

Comment: As long as the rule is not fully clear, I don't see how 1 should be correct and the numbers from 2 to 9 should be not correct. Or you could argue that the rule is only fulfilled if the number consists of at least two figures and add `if (strlen(buf) < 2) continue;` to the first `for` loop. EDIT: Make sure to add `#include <strings.h>`

Answer (score 0):

So here's another version based on arithmetic:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

_Bool only_consecutive_figures(int number)
{
    int figure, last;

    for (last = 0; number > 0; number /= 10) {
        figure = number % 10;
        if ((last != 0 && last != figure + 1) || figure == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        last = figure;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int m, n, i;

    puts("Enter m and n (m < n):");
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    if (m >= n) {
        fprintf(stderr, "m must be smaller than n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    puts("Output:");
    for (i = m; i < n; i++) {
        if (only_consecutive_figures(i)) {
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```